# Terraform Spot Instance inside VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I'm trying to launch a spot instance inside a VPC using Terraform.

I had a working `aws_instance` setup, and just changed it to `aws_spot_instance_request`, but I always get this error:

```
* aws_spot_instance_request.machine: Error requesting spot instances: InvalidParameterCombination: VPC security groups may not be used for a non-VPC launch
    status code: 400, request id: []
```

My `.tf` file looks like this:

```
provider "aws" {
    access_key = "${var.access_key}"
    secret_key = "${var.secret_key}"
    region     = "${var.region}"
}
resource "template_file" "userdata" {
    filename = "${var.userdata}"
    vars {
        domain = "${var.domain}"
        name   = "${var.name}"
    }
}
resource "aws_spot_instance_request" "machine" {
    ami = "${var.amiPuppet}"
    key_name = "${var.key}"
    instance_type = "c3.4xlarge"
    subnet_id = "${var.subnet}"
    vpc_security_group_ids = [ "${var.securityGroup}" ]
    user_data = "${template_file.userdata.rendered}"
    wait_for_fulfillment = true
    spot_price = "${var.price}"
    tags {
      Name = "${var.name}.${var.domain}"
      Provider = "Terraform"
    }
}
resource "aws_route53_record" "machine" {
    zone_id = "${var.route53ZoneId}"
    name = "${aws_spot_instance_request.machine.tags.Name}"
    type = "A"
    ttl = "300"
    records = ["${aws_spot_instance_request.machine.private_ip}"]
}
```

I don't understand why it isn't working... 
The [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/spot_instance_request.html) stands that `spot_instance_request` supports all parameters of `aws_instance`, so, I just changed a working `aws_instance` to `spot_instance_request` (with the addition of the price)... am I doing something wrong?

I originally opened this as an issue in [Terraform repo](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/3154), but no one replied me.

Comment: If you suspect it is a bug then I'm not sure you'll get much more out of SO than the github repo on which the project belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in terraform, seems to be fixed in master.

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/1339

Comment: Seems sad that you would post "its a bug" with out a bug number. Did you ever open a bug?

Comment: @JimmyDean sorry, I've fixed it.